# Why is my front room ceiling fan switch setting off my smoke alarms

Tags: electrical, lighting

When I come down in the morning and switch my ceiling fan on it sets off the fire alarms. It shouldn't be set off by a surge in the circuit as far as I know as the fan is downstairs and the smoke alarms are connected to the upstairs lighting circuit. I have got a box for the alarms on the wall with the option to locate alarm, test alarm and silence alarm but when I press the silence alarm button it just seems to reset the alarm and it goes off again. It only happens in the morning when the fan is first switched on.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. When did this start, and what changed? And, who's responsible for the fire alarms? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What make and model is your fire alarm panel?

Comment: What happns if you leave the ceiling fan on all night?   What if you then turn it off when you get up,  wait 3 or 4 hours,  then turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of smoke detectors, Ionization and photoelectric. If you have the latter, it might be that they have some particulate around the photocell and when the fan goes off it disturbs the dust enough to simulate smoke. If you know your type and manufacturer you can check your manual (many are online) and follow the cleaning procedures.

If you don't know the manufacturer sometimes you can bag the smoke detectors with a "shower cap" or a plastic bag and a rubber band and see if turning on the fans will set of the alarm.

After that it gets a little complicated and you might need to consult an alarm specialist in your area.

Good luck.

Comment: Also check if your smoke alarms are approaching or over 10 years old. If so they need to be replaced anyway due to end of life of the detector.  If they are dirty/dusty inside they are likely to be very old so do check.

Comment: The house was rewired by the council about 4 years ago and all brand new alarms was put in, there is a circuit breaker switch for the alarms but it is the same one as the upstairs light circuit breaker. There is a wall in between the fan and the alarm. It has also done it at night when I have turned the fan off but they only beep once when it happens at night and it ha only done it about 5 times at night. I have had to have the council out since and they found out that the screws in the back of the stitches and lights were loose.

Comment: Also about a year ago I had a problem where the landing and kitchen lights would just go off and after a while just come back on randomly. We checked the bulbs in other sockets and they worked fine, it only played up in the landing and kitchen light sockets. I dont really trust the new wiring as the electricians that rewired the house didnt have trunking big enough for the wires going into the main circuit board so they just used a hammer to hit them in.